# flips on labelled fatgraphs and mapping classes

Tags: co.combinatorics, mapping-class-groups, surfaces, teichmuller-theory

A fatgraph $G$ is a graph with a cyclic ordering of the edges at each vertex. A labelled fatgraph $(G,L)$ is a fatgraph together with a labelling $L$ of each edge. A labelled fatgraph spine $(G,L,e)$ is and embedding $e : G \to S$ in a surface $S$, up to isotopy, of a labelled fatgraph $(G,L)$. The mapping class group $MCG(S)$ of the surface acts on the set of labelled fatgraph spines. One can define a move that produces a new labelled fatgraph spine $(G',L',e')$ from $(G,L,e)$. The move is best described in terms of the dual triangulation of $(G,L,e)$, any edge $i$ of $G$ correspond to an edge of the dual triangulation and any vertex to a triangle. Removing the edge of the triangulation $i$ produces a square which can be completed in a single other way to a new triangulation of the surface. The move $W_i$ is defined to be the labelled fatgraph spine which is dual to this new triangulation, $W_i$ is called *flip*.

My first question is, do flips and elements of the mapping class group commute?
More explicitly, say that $\gamma \in MCG(S)$, $W_i$ is a flip on the labelled fatgraph spine $(G,L,e)$,
and be $\gamma(i)$ the edge of $\gamma ((G,L,e))$ corresponding to the edge $i$. Is it true that $\gamma \ \circ W_i = W_{\gamma(i)} \ \circ \gamma $?

My second question is the following. A mapping class group element can act on a labelled fatgraph spine as a permutation on its labelling (i.e. it does not change the connectivity of the underlying graph nor the isotopy classes of its edges), is it true that any permutation arise this way?